# Http post/get dynamic action url

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

Hello is it possible if someone could tell me the easiest way to create a dynamic action url on a html form.

We have 2 text box's and we would like to submit the information to a url like the following http://example.com/box1/box2/ but using the values contained within the forms text box's.

I guess this would need to be done via java script or something but i have no idea as to how to go about it.

Any help on this would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. All you need to do is to get the values from your script and then use header redirect. e.g.

```
if(isset($_POST['SUBMIT'] {
$box1 = $_POST['box1'];
$box2 = $_POST['box2']; 
header("Location: http://example.com/$box1/$box2/"); 
}
```

or you can use PHP curl library if you do not want to do a redirect

Answer (score 1):

if using javascript, guess u could do something like this, `php or server RewriteRule` (.htaccess) might be what u r looking for.

```
<script>

//replace the textbox1 and 2 with the id of your text boxes in your form
var box1=document.getElementById('textbox1').value;
var box2=document.getElementById('textbox2').value;

window.location ="http://example.com/"+box1+"/"+box2+"/"; 

</script>
```

Might want to put the script into a function and call it with an 'onclick=' event or if u want to call the javascript before the form submits. try using 'onsubmit=' with return=false; at the end of the function.

hope it helps